# iFrame refused to load inside a React Native Webview

Tags: react-native, iframe, webview, content-security-policy, react-native-webview

I'm building a React Native (expo) app and I need to display an iFrame with some content that I do not control.

I'm using `react-native-webview` to display a webview like so

```
<WebView
        ref={ref}
        onMessage={handleMessages}
        injectedJavaScript={injectedJs}
        source={{
          html: `
            <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html>
              <head>
                <script src="https://cdn.some-script-I-do-not-control.js"></script>
                <title>Pge title</title>
              </head>
              <body>
              </body>
            </html>
          `
        }}
        originWhitelist={['*']}
      />
```

After the page loads, the script that I do not control adds an iFrame to the body and displays stuff. In my case the webview loads fine and the script executes without error until the iFrame tries to load, then I get the classic: (in the webview's console)

`Refused to load https://the-iframe-website.wow/ because it does not appear in the frame-ancestors directive of the Content Security Policy.`

Since I do not control the website loaded by the iFrame, I cannot play with the content-security-policy, but when I inspect the network request I can see that the CSP header actually includes `frame-ancestors *` which is supposed to be the wildcard to allow any url if I read the w3 doc correctly. Also, this same script setup works perfectly fine in the browser and on desktop, it just refuses to load inside a webview, which is weird.

Has anyone ever seen something like this or have ideas of things to try? Because I'm currently running out .

All of this is on iOS, haven't tried on Android yet because I do not have an Android device atm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone stumbles on this, the error was due to the fact that I was loading the iFrame in an about:blank (created by react-native-webview) and this is not supported by CSP.

I had to host a real blank page somewhere to embed the iFrame inside and I got it working!

Comment: cannot explain more about it.